Crowdstrike IT outage flight cancellations and EU 261 compensation trend
It has been a few weeks now since the Crowdstrike IT problem related flight cancellations around 19th July.
I was curious, have airlines been honoring their EU mandatory compensation obligations or treating this as an extraordinary circumstance beyond their control and denying claims?
Just curious if other have any experience on this especially from airlines flying EU routes.
Also, has any of the aviation regulators taken a stand on this? Whether they will require airlines to pay  compensation or treat this as an extraordinary circumstance?

It is always extraordinary circumstance. Like insurance, you get very often a no as an answer (as pre-filter), so just answers from airline will not help. You need to ask further and further until you get money (or a satisfying explanation or a decision from civilian authorities). So it is way to early. -- And it may depend case by case. Airline crowdstrike: probably not. Airport, maybe. Aircontrol authorities: possibly.

I've been using the German version of Google, and the first through third website all say, that a technical issue at the airport is considered an extraordinary circumstance by the airline, and so there would be no compensation in terms of money. Airlines are still obliged to offer meals, alternative transportation and hotel rooms where necessary or refund the ticket price if the customer prefers.
First result: https://www.drboese.de/blog/it-ausfall-vom-19-juli-2024-und-ihre-fluggastrechte/
Second result: https://www.merkur.de/reise/flughaefen-technische-probleme-it-stoerung-weltweit-rechte-flugreisende-passagiere-zr-93196058.html
Third result: https://www.rundschau-online.de/ratgeber/verbraucher/weltweite-computer-stoerung-welche-rechte-fluggaeste-nach-dem-it-ausfall-haben-830860
The latter mentions that things could be different if the airline itself was affected by the outage, but also that this might be hard to prove.

On day 1, airports were in chaos; it would be easy (and possibly correct) for airlines to blame airports.  However, after a few days many airports were handling flights from most airlines.  It's at that point where it becomes a bit harder for the airlines to blame the airports.  Mind you, I'm speaking from a US perspective, where it was especially blatant that some airlines were affected more than others.  I'm unsure how true that is in the EU.
