Easyjet denied EU261 compensation for flight cancellation during Crowdstrike: Any escalation or other recourse?
I had a flight cancellation by Easyjet on 19 July during the Crowdstrike outage. I applied for EU261 compensation and Easyjet has denied it claiming circumstances outside their control.
Do I have any recourse? Is there a way to appeal or should I give up?
Flight was from Copenhagen Denmark to Basel Switzerland.
More specifically, has anyone had success escalating to Alternate Dispute resolution forums like CEDR or the UK or other EU regulators? I'm trying to see if there is a precedent already established for Crowdstrike related claims or the equivalent of a class action lawsuit?
Of course, if the regulators have taken a public position that Crowdstrike related cancellations are exempt, then escalation could be moot.

Which systems were affected? Those of EasyJet, or those of the airport or air traffic control for instance? In the latter case it is deemed to be outside the control of the airline. In the former case it’s still up in the air as far as I know.

Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/190618/crowdstrike-it-outage-flight-cancellations-and-eu-261-compensation-trend

Note: rejection are nearly automatic for most cases. Many people will stop at first rejection, and so full gain to airline. So you should reply and ask for more information and telling them your interpretation. A good email nearly ready to be sent to national authorities will help, especially if you tell them that if they do not provide good reasons you will contact them (so add evidences [do not rely that airlines know times and what they told passengers, write them in the email] and motivation)

Possibly related, law-side: Do tech companies like Microsoft & CrowdStrike face almost no legal liabilities for major disruptions?

For a CPH-BSL flight, the point of escalation is Danish Trafikstyrelsen, which is free of charge.
If you abandoned the trip entirely, you're due a full refund regardless of extraordinary circumstances. If you continued your trip, you're due reimbursement of expenses for meals, accommodation and local transport in Copenhagen, to be claimed HERE by sending in receipts. If easyJet didn't offer re-routing within a suitable timeframe, and you re-routed yourself on a different airline as a result, that flight ticket is also to be reimbursed by easyJet.
Compensation (EUR 250) will depend on the circumstances for the cancellation, so again if that's been refused escalate to Trafikstyrelsen.

Thanks! I lodged a complaint with the Danish authority online.

@curious_cat If they owe you any expenses, hopefully you claimed for that at the same time

@crqzydre indeed. Expenses claimed for as well.

Depends on what exactly you mean by "compensation". A cursory google search seems to indicate that most "experts" agree that this was indeed outside what as "reasonably foreseeable and in the control of the airline" and no cash compensation is due. However, we won't know for sure until someone takes it to court and we get a verdict.
This being said, the airline has still "duty of care", which means full refund or rebooking, expenses for food, accommodation, alternative transportation etc. where applicable. We can expect the airlines to drag their feet on these claims so it might take months or years and a few court decision to fully sort this out.

EasyJet's IT services are EasyJet's responsability. They cannot say "a provider did a bad thing" anymore than a restaurant can evade responsability for food poisoning because it was its provider's fault. What is relevant is what IT services were down which caused the failure; if EasyJet was working fine but the airport could not operate then it is certainly beyond EasyJey control because they have no responsability on the airport's IT.

@SJuan76 The regulation does not say that EasyJet pays compensation for all failures under their responsibility. You are creating something that doesn't exist. EasyJet is explicitly released for compensation under "extraordinary circumstances which could not have been avoided even if all reasonable measures had been taken," which includes issues under EasyJet's responsibility.

@SJuan76 The airport’s IT is beyond EasyJet’s control, but the terms of EasyJet’s contract with the airport are entirely within its control (given that it can simply refuse to use an airport that won’t agree to an acceptable contract), and those terms should specify that the airport covers EasyJet’s costs for compensating customers for delays caused by the airport’s failings. If they don’t, then that’s on EasyJet.

@SJuan76: they will definitely say "this is not our fault" until such time a court decides that it is. That's the way it works: the law is written with good intent but poor wording and a lot of ambiguity so it comes down to the courts to decide the details.

@Hilmar I agree. I am trying to see if anyone has gone to court on this already or would I be the first one to try? Any class actions i could join would make it easier.

@SJuan76 they're not, at least not completely. The airline's IT systems depend on external sources for information for example, if those sources are down the airline's systems are down outside of the airline's responsibility. The airline also depends on systems run by the airport directly. For example at AMS the check in desks were down, and the systems governing ground handling, so no aircraft could operate. Again, the airline has no responsibility there.

This answer and some of the discussion in the comments seems to hinge on what's under the (direct) control of the airline. This is just irrelevant under the letter of the law. The only exception is for “extraordinary circumstances”, i.e. things the airlines could not reasonably plan for. There is a lot of bad faith from airlines but actually no ambiguity in the law about that.

@jwenting Responsibility is entirely absent from EU261, airline have obligations based on delays and cancellations whether they are at fault or not. If airlines were off the hook for planning for, mitigating, and remediating failures in their supply chain (aircraft, air traffic control, ground handling, airport) or things outside their control (including the weather), the regulation would basically be void save for the odd case where the crew is missing for some reason. This is not the way it was written or interpreted by case law.

There are various companies that specialize in litigating EU261 claims. They typically work on a no-cure-no-pay basis, usually taking around a 30% cut. It is worth considering if you have no other options remaining: while it is a shame you have to give up part of your compensation, they take on the risk if the litigation is unsuccessful and they know the applicable laws very, very well.

I checked and there companies are not accepting Crowdstrike related claims so far as I understand.

Just to summarise the solution steps:
Easyjet denied my compensation.
I've escalated to Aviation ADR for arbitration and also filed a complaint with the Danish regulator ( since the flight was from Copenhagen)
I will update here if I get any productive responses.
Next step would be UK small claims court I guess. If others have any tips on this I am glad to hear them.
Especially if there's a formal stand by an aviation regulator or a class action. Or precedents of others taking an airline to court over Crowdstrike and what the court ruled.
